# dialogFlow @sys.number-sequence only works for English

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm building an Action for Google Assistant using dialogFlow, and it has to support multiple languages(EN, NL, FR).
I have a PinIntent, where I want to use `@sys.number-sequence` entity in my utterance.

It works on EN version, but when I use the same entity for NL or FR I get the following error and can't save the intent.

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

[image]

I don't want to use `@sys.number`, if the pincode is `0123` it will return `123`, which will not match in my webhook.

I also don't want to use `@sys.any`, this will basically listen to all input...

Is there a tutorial where I can create a custom entity based on other entities?
eg. `@pincode`, which will map to `0000`, `one two three four`, `1 2 3 4`, `one 2 34`, `thousandtwohunderdthirtyfour`, ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the Dialogflow system entities documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities#num-nl), `@sys.number-sequence` currently isn't available in NL or FR. Regarding this question:

> Is there a tutorial where I can create a custom entity based on other entities? eg. @pincode, which will map to 0000, one two three four, 1 2 3 4, one 2 34, thousandtwohunderdthirtyfour,

This is called a [composite entity](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/developer-entities#developer_composite).

Comment: I accepted this answer, because it answers my original question, but creating a composite entity, didn't solved my problem of creating a pincode entity. I end up creating a workaround... basically creating 10 "dummy"-entities (pincode1-1, pincode1-2, pincode2-1, ...), then creating a composite entity pincode with all the "dummy"-entities in it. those dummy entities contains all the possibilities("zero0one3", "1 2 3 4", "00 12", ...). And I created it in parts, because dialogFlow has a limit on synonyms and doing 0000 until 9999 is a lot :P